# Delay starting activity from receiver on screen off

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a lock screen for Android 4.0+. I'm using a service that registers a receiver for screen OFF. This receiver launches an activity onReceived.

The problem is that this whole process is not fast enough. The receiver has a minor delay, but the real problem is the launch of the activity, that takes like 3-4 seconds.

I've seen similar apps, like:
https://github.com/Pi-Developers/Pi-Locker.
In this case, everything works perfectly, but i can't figure out what I'm doing differently.

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxx" >


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LockScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter> >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".LockBoot"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".LockReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".LockerService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:process=":background" >
        </service>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

</manifest>
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LockerService.class);
        startService(i);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**LockerService**

```
public class LockerService extends Service {


    static SharedPreferences spf;
    static Context c;
    int mActive;
    String on;
    LockReceiver mReceiver = new LockReceiver();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;

    }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            return START_STICKY;
        }


    /**
     * 
     * mStaus is Variable of int we need to find status of locker to make it
     * enable or disable 
     * 
     **/

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        mActive = 1; //todo

        if (mActive == 0) {

            stopSelf();
            return;

        }

        if (mActive == 1) {

            try {

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                intentFilter.setPriority(9999);

            registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);


            } catch (Exception e) {

                unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

            }

        } else  {

            try {
                unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            } catch(Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();


        /**
         * 
         * make sure service still running 
         *
         */

            startService(new Intent(LockerService.this , LockerService.class));


    }

}
```

**LockReceiver**

```
public class LockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        TelephonyManager ts = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        int callState = ts.getCallState();

        if (callState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        }

    }
}
```

LockScreenActivity is just an empty activity, with a simple layout. No actions yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: how many devices you tried on?

Comment: Did you mean to say, your activity is shown below the default lock screen?

Comment: No, i've removed the default lock screen. The point is that the activity is not ready when you turn off and turn on the screen quickly. You have to wait 3-4 seconds for it to appear.

Comment: @jonyjm, please log all scenario, check which section takes time delay.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your IntentFilter, where you set the priority:

```
intentFilter.setPriority(9999);
```

Now look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) regarding intentfilters:

> The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a
>   higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater
>   than -1000 and less than 1000

Comment: I've changed the priority to 999, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: I'd replace `9999` with `IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY - 1` to be more accurate